# JTabbedPane with JTextAreas. Automatically scroll down

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jtabbedpane

I´ve got a JTabbedPane with JTextAreas as Components. With another methode I add Texts to the TextAreas. But if the TextArea is full it doesnt scroll down, so I can´t see the latest texts. How can I solve this?

```
    public class View extends JFrame{

    public class Field extends JTextArea{
    public Field(){
        this.setEditable(false);
        this.setLineWrap(true);
        DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret)this.getCaret();
        caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
    }

}

    public View(){


    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.tabs = new JTabbedPane();
    this.tabs.add("abc", new Field());

    this.add(tabs, BorderLayout.CENTER);

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your `JTextArea` inside of a `JScrollPane` to make it scrollable:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret;
import java.awt.*;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret)textArea.getCaret();
        caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);

        JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        jScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab("abc", jScrollPane);

        jFrame.setContentPane(tabbedPane);

        jFrame.pack();
        jFrame.setVisible(true);

        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i ++) {
            textArea.append(i + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But If I add the scrollPane to my code nothing changes. I cant see the scrollPane. Is it possible that the problem is created by the BorderLayout? Because the TextArea has also not the size I set to it

Comment: With the OP's setting of caret policy to ALWAYS_UPDATE, the call to setCaretPosition should not be needed. And if using another update policy, the call to setCaretPosition should be done once, after the loop,

Comment: @Alex I have updated my answer to more closely match the format of your code.